# Push Workspace with multiple projects on Bitbucket repository

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, bitbucket, xcode-workspace

I have Xcode workspace which has multiple projects - the main project and a pod project. How do I push the code (the first time) on Bitbucket so that everything is set on repository ? Attached is the project structure just for clarification

[image]

This is the folder structure I have

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you got to do is go to the Project folder in Terminal and follow the below commands in the same order. I am assuming both your main project and pod project are inside the same folder

So in terminal go inside your first AppIT folder. If you run command `ls -l` in terminal on that folder you will see a list of all folders and files inside it like AppIt, .xcodeProj file, Pod folder, Podfile etc. Just run the below commands on that location where you see this list.

```
git init
git add -A .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/.... .git // your complete URL
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: No. the main and pod projects are in different folder.

Comment: And you want them to be committed in 1 Repository? Then you would have to create a parent folder which contains both of these and then create a repo inside the parent fodler

Comment: Edited my question and added screenshot showing folder structure.

Comment: Man this is in the same folder so you are lucky.  Go till your AppIT folder which is the main folder and inside it run the above commands. It will commit all files including your project and pods

Comment: On git commit -m "first commit" I have getting the following message : Untracked files:
 AppIT.xcodeproj/

 AppIT.xcworkspace/
 AppIT/
 Build/
 Podfile
 Podfile.lock
 Pods/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Comment: Yayyyy. That worked. Personally speaking, this is far more easy that setting up from Xcode.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does **git add -A** do ? Will this be required even if I have a single project ?

Comment: Yes it will be required. This adds all your files to be tracked for git repo. if you do -A . that means all files in the folder, if you say -A filename, it will only add that file. You need to do this everytime if you are adding new files to repo.